# WordPress saved JSON in database

Tags: json, wordpress

I have saved some array using wordpress core functionality and array data has saved in database like

```
a:4:{s:22:"activities_connect_url";s:85:"http://example.com/endpoint";s:16:"activities_agent";s:3:"SOME_AGENT";s:18:"activities_api_key";s:32:"SOME_API_KEY";s:21:"activities_secret_key";s:36:"SOME_SECRET_KEY";}
```

why like that and if I want to decode it without wordpress core functionality, it is very tough.

is there any easy way to decode it without WP core functionality?

Comment: This is serialized data, have a look at [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to "decode" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, WordPress stored data serialized. To see actual data of yours you need to first unserialize it.

[Check PHP unserialize method for know more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)